# PostgreSQL database - only insert if the record doesn't exist

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Cannot SELECT from UPDATE RETURNING clause in postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7191902/cannot-select-from-update-returning-clause-in-postgres)

I am using a PostgreSQL database which has a "company" table and a "country" table which each have a uniqueID.

I want a setup where if I try to add a company to the database, it only adds the company to the database with a new unique ID if it doesn't already exist.

Comment: this has already been asked/solved

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
insert into company (unique_id, company_name)
select 42, 'New Company Name'
from company
where not exists (select 1 from company where unique_id = 42);
```

See also here for a more general solution: [Insert, on duplicate update in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109061/insert-on-duplicate-update-postgresql)